# imageview not set full screen

Tags: android

I set image view to full screen but it doesn't work: there is some space in between left and right side. How to set the `imageview` to full screen?

this is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">  
   </ImageView>  
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

use  `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in your xml:

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"  
       android:layout_width="match_parent"  
       android:layout_height="match_parent"  
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
/>
```

Comment: Also use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent`. `fill_parent` is considered as deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of following options

```
android:scaleType="CENTER_CROP"
```

Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

```
android:scaleType="CENTER_INSIDE"
```

Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Scale in X and Y independently, so that src matches dst exactly.

If you don't care about ratio

```
ImageView imageView=new ImageView(context);
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(false);
```

Comment: in xml I'm pretty sure you want to use "centerInside"/"centerCrop" for android:scaleType or you'll get an error